# Calling Python from J

Tags: python, j

I'm trying to connect Python to J, in the same way that R connects so nicely to J via the package here:

http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Interfaces/R/Rserve/Installation

I have been able to use all the R packages I would ever want, via the J-to-Rserve interface. I wonder if a similar interface might exist for Python, and if so where I might find it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Python, but this was discussed in a Google group in 2013 and although there have been a couple of updates to J since then, it may be worth a look.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/j-programming/XoS3Vmf19k4